# Kernel "update" to 3.19.0.68.50 after upgrading to 4.4.0-34?

Tags: release-freya, kernel, updates

I recently installed the new hardware enablement stack including kernel 4.4.0-34. Today the update manager told me there was a kernel update available - to kernel version 3.19.0.68.50.

I haven't "upgraded" yet because I'm wondering if this is a bug. Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes ago I got 4.4.0-36 update. Looks like that the update manager try to update both versions without checking whats  really running.

Deesnook, in the update manager it shows under technical description which version will be updated to the new one. Which old version was it in your case?

Comment: same here, update manager offers me to update two kernel sets: 3.19.0.66.48 to 3.19.0.68.50 AND 4.4.0.34.24 to 4.4.0.36.26.
I haven't run either update yet. 
Sounds like you ran the update to 4.4.0.36 though? Did that work? What about the other update, does it still show in update manager?

Comment: Right, I update to 4.4.0.36.26 without problems. System works since 2 days problem free. I have removed all old 3.19 kernel files.

Comment: ah ok, sure, if you remove the older kernel versions there won't be any problem. I guess I'll just wait. Looks like Loki will arrive within one week :)